# Filters in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a small application in Vuejs 2.0, where I'm using [v-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) component, I'm having a data format something like this:

```
{
    "model":
        [
            {
                "id":1,
                "salutation":"Mr",
                "first_name":"Rahul",
                "last_name":"Bashisht",
                "number":"9876521102",
                "email":"rahul@icicibank.com",
                "company":
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"ICICI Bank",
                        "is_client":1,
                    }
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "salutation":"Mr",
                "first_name":"Vikash",
                "last_name":"Pandey",
                "number":"0987654345",
                "email":"vikash@hdfc.com",
                "company":
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"HDFC Bank",
                        "is_client":0,
                    }
            }
        ]
}
```

Now I'm setting this to a variable `model` and then trying to filter with `client = 1` in `computed property` something like this:

```
contactClients: function() {
    if(this.model)
    {
        return this.model
            .filter(f => (f.company.is_client == 1))
            .map(d => ({label: d.first_name+' '+d.last_name+' - '+d.company.name, value: d.id}))
    }
},
```

Then I'm placing it in v-select options as:

```
<v-select multiple :options="contactClients" v-model="clientParticipants"></v-select>
```

Now I'm having a other v-select which is in accordance with company name but is_client is true, so I'm trying something like this:

I've data set of companies:

```
{
    "model":
        [
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"ICICI Bank",
                "is_client":1,
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"HDFC Bank",
                "is_client": 0,
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "name":"BNP Paribas",
                "is_client": 0,
            }
            {
                "id":4,
                "name":"Barclays Bank",
                "is_client": 1,
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm placing it in `companies` variable and filtering it something like this:

```
clients: function () {
    if(this.companies)
    {
        return this.companies
            .filter(f => f.is_client == 1)
            .map(d => ({label: d.name, value: d.id}))
    }
}
```

And in v-select I'm having:

```
<v-select :options="clients" v-model="summary.client"></v-select>
```

I want to have an extra filter in accordance to the selection of `contactsClients`, i.e. if any `contactsClients` are being selected in the first list, second list should have only those `company` as option and if there is no selection in first list(contactClients) then second list should have all default options with simple `is_client` filter which is in current situation. Since the selection in `contactClients` is multiple so I don't know how to filter elements. Please guide me.

**Edit:** [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZaOEQ?editors=1010)

Comment: could you provide jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @Pradeepb Please have a look: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZaOEQ?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will help you.

```
contactClients: function() {
  if (this.model) {
    return this.model.filter(f => f.company.is_client == 1).map(d => ({
      label: d.first_name + " " + d.last_name + " - " + d.company.name,
      value: d.id,
      companyId: d.company.id
    }));
  }
},
clients: function() {
  var self = this;
  var res = [];
  if (this.companies) {

    if (this.clientParticipants.length) {
      console.log(this.clientParticipants)
      this.clientParticipants.forEach(function(cc) {
        self.companies.forEach(function(c) {
          if (cc.companyId === c.id) {
            res.push(c);
          }
        });
      });
      return res.map(d => ({ label: d.name, value: d.id }));
    } else {
      return this.companies
        .filter(f => f.is_client == 1)
        .map(d => ({ label: d.name, value: d.id }));
    }
  }
}
```

example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLePLL?editors=1010)

Comment: You are comparing with the id `(cc.value === c.id)`, but both contact id and company id are different, they are not same.

Comment: Ok so what’s the relation between them? There should be some common factor between them to compare right?

Comment: Once you fetch the contacts from `model` it comes with the companies data too under the key `company`, here you can see each contact has company name and ID under `company key`.

Comment: nope. Since you are modifying it in the `contactClients` computed values, it will have only `label` and `value`.  check [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLePLL?editors=1010). I have modified it.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But the core data set has these values. I guess we can find from the contact model data set and map the values.

Comment: Yes that work, but may be we can have `company.id` instead of `company.name` check, any ways I'll modify it, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I feel that will be too much of computation. My modified answer should solve your issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed property to implement your filter logic there and bind it to your second list.
Ref.: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties

Comment: I'm already making these lists inside my computed property, the selection list is an array (multiple) and I'm not sure how to have filter multiple times